# how to create Proximity Sensor observer?

Tags: iphone, ios, proximitysensor

i want to create and observer that checks for a change in proximity sensor. i am using this code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(proximityChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];
```

but it give an error of "Use of undeclared identifier 'device'"

please help.

Comment: check out my code...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(proximityChanged:)
                                                     name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification"
                                                   object:nil];
```

Do like this way you set nil to objcet.